# How to edit image when saved in Edited folder

Tags: java, android

I have spent the last day or so trying to do this on my own without any luck.

I am wondering if it is my specific device (galaxy nexus - the edited image is being saved in /mnt/sdcard/Edited) which causes the limited advice on this subject not to work as expected.

My problem is when i start an intent to edit an image using third party app (photo studio) I can edit the image but never actually get it back.

I never get a callback to onActivityResponse no matter what calling code I try (i have gone through every google result which contains ACTION_EDIT to see how others are doing it),

so no response meant I had to try another way - according to a post somewhere i found the edited image should be saved over the image you send to the app if you specify some categories and data tags in your manifest which i implemented and spent a few hours on  but to no avail - the image i sent was always the same image when onResume was called.

So I have been trying another approach, listen for changes in file system using..

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, myObserver);
```

and I get a result of sorts - my onChanged method is called when the image has been edited and saved for which i can receive an id but never am i able to build the correct uri to get the file path using

```
 String columns[] = new String[]{ Media._ID, Media.DATA, Media.DISPLAY_NAME,      Media.MIME_TYPE, Media.SIZE, Media.MINI_THUMB_MAGIC };


  Uri image     = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, latestId);

  Cursor cursor = application.managedQuery(image, columns, null, null, null);
```

however, I always end up with a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION using the above lines of code in a while loop (this is based on some kind kindly put out there to do with a AlbumUploader).

I hope somebody can give me a shout on where I am going wrong or a workaround to get proper file path for such a situation.

Regards, thanks for reading.